# While creating http post request i get 0 bytes

Tags: ios, swift, api, http, post

the following is my code:

```
let session = URLSession.shared
let url = URL.init(string: "http://popularcarsoman.dev.techneek.in/appgateway/endPoint.php")
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
let parameter = ["action":"FEATUREDCARS"]
do {
   urlRequest.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameter, options: .prettyPrinted)
}
catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
    if (error != nil) {
        let alert = UIAlertController.init(title: "Oops!", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction.init(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }else {
        print("hello")
        print(data ?? Data())
    }
}
dataTask.resume()
```

Comment: You are creating a `http` request have you added exceptions in plist ?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It is unclear what you are asking or what the errors are.

Comment: @amrit Giri - Check your console log. For every Http request, you must add the key for  AppTranport Security in your info.plist file. Without the key, your request will be failed.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with parameter encoding in `POST` request body, currently you are using `JSONEncoding`, but at your server end they are accepting `httpBody`. Below the complete implementation for your request:

```
func callWebService() {
        var config                              :URLSessionConfiguration!
        var urlSession                          :URLSession!

        config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        urlSession = URLSession(configuration: config)

        let callURL = URL.init(string: "http://popularcarsoman.dev.techneek.in/appgateway/endPoint.php")

        var request = URLRequest.init(url: callURL!)

        request.timeoutInterval = 60.0 // TimeoutInterval in Second
        request.cachePolicy = URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let param = "action=FEATUREDCARS"
        let data = param.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)
        request.httpBody = data

        let dataTask = urlSession.dataTask(with: request) { (data,response,error) in
            if error != nil{
                return
            }

        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
```